# Get updates on questions and answers pop up can no longer be dismissed by clicking the X

Tags: bug, popups, follow-post

The get updates on questions and answers pop up can no longer be dismissed by clicking the X, it was working before but seems broken now.

[image]

My capture is from Philosophy and this was also reported at [Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19015/get-updates-ok-box-does-not-disappear#19015)

Update: It seems to work again, I don't know what the issue was.

Comment: Works with no problem on Windows 10, Firefox 74.0. Tested on Worldbuilding

Comment: @Jenayah It seems to work again now on all sites, no idea what happened here.