# Follow popup won't clear (without refresh)

Tags: bug, follow-post

The first time visiting a stack with the new follow mechanic, you get the "*Get updates on questions and answers*" popup.

If the "follow" link is clicked, there is strange behavior. Clicking the X on the "get updates" popup closes the "unfollow" popup and the "get updates" popup will not go away.

The workaround here is a page refresh, which will clear the "get updates" popup.

[image: follow bug]

I'm using Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit) for Windows 10.

Comment: @Bitter you might be thinking of [Get updates on questions and answers pop up can no longer be dismissed by clicking the X](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345947/232439), which does look like the same issue. But they don't have the steps to reproduce. I'm guessing they clicked "follow" like I did at first and ran into the issue. But then on another site they just clicked the X and called it fixed.

Comment: When I wrote that yesterday, I had no idea if I pressed the follow button first or not but it seems a safe bet it is the same issue.